# A rather creepy duo

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Black is the mother, white is the daughter
>   Life is their enemy, death is their friend
>   One never speaking, one never silent
>   Where one is, the other will be in the end

Who or what are they?

Comment: Was thinking Magicicadas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodical_cicadas) but "Life is their enemy death is their friend" does not seem to fit.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> A fly/housefly, and a maggot

Black is the mother, white is the daughter

> Flies are black, maggots are white

Life is their enemy, death is their friend

> Humans try to squat/kill them, but flies lay their egg into dead animals, which provide food for maggots

One never speaking, one never silent

> Maggots don't speak. Flies buzz all the time (with a bit of a stretch, most insects buzz, but house flies generally don't)

Where one is, the other will be in the end

> The adult form of maggots are flies. And flies lay their eggs on meat, where maggots hatch from them, so if a fly is there, the maggot(s) will follow.

Comment: You are correct!

Answer (score 30):

Black is the mother, white is the daughter

> The Raven is the mother, the daughter is a white egg

Life is their enemy, death is their friend

> As immortalized in "The Raven" by Edgar Allen Poe..

One never speaking, one never silent

> Its pretty quiet in the egg.  And as for the bird: Caw-Caw, Caw-Caw!

Where one is, the other will be in the end

> Eggs hatch!

Comment: This is really creative!  Not the intended answer, though, and line 2 is a bit of a stretch, particularly where the daughter is concerned.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps:

> Turkey vulture (or alternatively a Black vulture)

Black is the mother, white is the daughter

> As adults they are black. The chicks of the Turkey vulture [are white](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vnPR1O-tTvc/maxresdefault.jpg) though. (The chicks of the Black vulture are more [dark beige](http://dfwurbanwildlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/blackvulture-nestupdate5-002.jpg).)

Life is their enemy, death is their friend

> They are scavengers, eating from dead animals. As long as these animals are still alive they have nothing to eat, but as soon as the animals die they'll have plenty to eat.

One never speaking, one never silent

> Not sure about the first part, since the adults also make sounds. But the "*one never silent*" could be for the chick begging for food. As all birds, chicks begging for food try to make as much noise as possible to alert the parents.

Where one is, the other will be in the end

> The chick will grow up and will one day be a mother herself.

Comment: Good guess! As you pointed out, though, the third line is a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the intended answer, but it works:

> The night sky and the moon

Black is the mother, white is the daughter

> The night sky is black, the moon is white. (Also both are often depicted as female in mythology.)

Life is their enemy, death is their friend

> Most living things sleep during the night

One never speaking, one never silent

> The sky is silent.  The moon inspires the howls of dogs and wolves, and also chirping insects, frogs, etc. that are normally quiet when the moon is not visible.

Where one is, the other will be in the end

> The moon appears in the sky, and moves across it.  Where at one point the only thing that can be seen is sky, later the moon may be there.

Answer (score 1):

> A black hole and a white hole.
>  The white hole is theoretically the daughter of a black hole.
>  Nothing can live around them.
>  A black hole absorbs everything, a white hole does not absorb anything.
>  The destiny of all black holes may be a white hole.

Comment: This is an interesting concept--but it isn't what I was going for (and the third line is a bit of a stretch).

Comment: @DLosc is the personification of the solution as females in the riddle significant?

Comment: @Abhishek Somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

> Two wormhole mouths.

Black is the mother, white is the daughter

> One end would be a black hole, the other (perhaps in a different universe) is a white hole.

Life is their enemy, death is their friend

> They are created by the *death* of a star (supernova). The black hole kills/crushes any life that enters.

One never speaking, one never silent

> Black holes emit no sound since they suck up any medium it could transfer through. White holes would constantly emit sound (to anyone within the atmosphere its emitting).

Where one is, the other will be in the end

> The white whole is at the end of the wormhole, where the entrance is the black hole.